# Is there a way to get the current value of some entity field from the DB which I have changed and am about to update?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code:

```
String someFieldNewValue = entity.getSomeField();
String someFieldOldValue = someRepository.getOne(entity.getId()).getSomeField();
someRepository.save(entity);
createHistoryEntry(someFieldNewValue, someFieldOldValue);
```

`someEntity` is an already existing entity in the DB to which the value of `someField` has been changed and needs to be updated.
What I need to do is to get the old value of `someField` (the one in the DB before `someRepository.save(entity)`, which is going to be updated) to create a history entry for the update, but my problem is that both `someFieldNewValue` and `someFieldOldValue` variables have the same value (the new one).

How do I get the old value of `someField`, having the id of the entity?

Comment: I don't have a full explanation for the entire workflow here, but if you capture the field value as soon as you load it into your Hibernate context, you can avoid the need to go back to the database like this at the last minute.

Answer (score 0):

The proper flow of update 1 record, having the id of the entity and create a history entry  when using JPA:

1. Find the record you want to update (probably by findById method)
2. If found nothing, throw NotFoundException.
   If found, make a oldEntity which is the copy of the entity you found then update the entity
3. Save the entity
4. Create the history entry with the oldEntity

- With the flow above, you should be able to accquire what you want.
- If what you mean is **someFieldNewValue** and **someFieldOldValue** have the same value so you can't compare to create the history entry then in your table it should have column **created** and **modified** to help you compare it.